# How is int() implemented in Python?

Tags: python, binary

How does it convert binary numbers to base 10 as quickly as it does?  bin() returns a string, how does it convert them to integers to do the math on them?

Comment: `int` does not convert integers to base 10. It converts strings, or numeric objects such as floats, to the internal representation for integers (which I think is always two's complement).

Comment: [Use a source, Luke!](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/intobject.c). Is `PyInt_FromString` what you want?

Comment: Basically some splaining, other than RTFS, that I obviously understand is an option.  It's not entirely clear to me how C and Python interact in instances such as this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use int plus extra parameter to convert it

```
int('1000', 2)
output:
8
```

int class:

```
class int(x, base=10)
```

> Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or
>   return 0 if no arguments are given. If x is a number, it can be a
>   plain integer, a long integer, or a floating point number. If x is
>   floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero. If the argument
>   is outside the integer range, the function returns a long object
>   instead.
>
> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string or
>   Unicode object representing an integer literal in radix base.
>   Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space in
>   between) and surrounded by whitespace. A base-n literal consists of
>   the digits 0 to n-1, with a to z (or A to Z) having values 10 to 35.
>   The default base is 10. The allowed values are 0 and 2-36. Base-2, -8,
>   and -16 literals can be optionally prefixed with 0b/0B, 0o/0O/0, or
>   0x/0X, as with integer literals in code. Base 0 means to interpret the
>   string exactly as an integer literal, so that the actual base is 2, 8,
>   10, or 16.